# Phusion Passenger not starting: "sudo: passenger: command not found"

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, passenger, sudo

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 server and successfully installed Phusion Passenger. I'm getting the following errors when I try to start it:

```
christy@beast0:/$ passenger status
Phusion Passenger Standalone is not running, according to PID file /passenger.3000.pid
christy@beast0:/$ passenger start
Stopping web server.../home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemon_controller-0.2.6/lib/daemon_controller/lock_file.rb:63:in `initialize': Permission denied - /passenger.3000.pid.lock (Errno::EACCES)
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemon_controller-0.2.6/lib/daemon_controller/lock_file.rb:63:in `open'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemon_controller-0.2.6/lib/daemon_controller/lock_file.rb:63:in `exclusive_lock'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemon_controller-0.2.6/lib/daemon_controller.rb:269:in `stop'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:466:in `block in stop_nginx'
from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:463:in `stop_nginx'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:94:in `rescue in run'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:98:in `run'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:93:in `block in run_command'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:48:in `block in each_command'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:43:in `each'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:43:in `each_command'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:91:in `run_command'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:62:in `run!'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:39:in `run!'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/bin/passenger:32:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/bin/passenger:19:in `load'
from /home/christy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/bin/passenger:19:in `<main>'
christy@beast0:/$ sudo passenger start
sudo: passenger: command not found`
```

Ideas?

Comment: Did you happen to install Passenger with `sudo` privileges?

Comment: Presumably the pid file is there to prevent you from starting a second instance. The `sudo` error suggests that `passenger` is not installed in the default `PATH`. Try forcibly removing the pid file (perhaps with `sudo rm`) then start the process as yourself.

Comment: @Evan Yes I did. I followed the instructions here: http://bit.ly/y1Aywo since initially I got the same error ("sudo: passenger-install-apache2-module: command not found").

Comment: I did the Apache/mod_rails setup once on my Ubuntu VPS server and followed this series of articles: http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/5/1/ubuntu-hardy-mod_rails-installation (The Ubuntu version shouldn't really matter) It might be worth a look to compare notes with it to see if you missed any steps -

Comment: @Evan Thanks for the link, but I'm afraid that I didn't miss anything. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @tripleee Do you know where the PID file would be? I checked my app/tmp, /usr, and root directory, but nothing like that is there! Thanks!

Comment: By the looks of the output, it is trying to use the riot directory. Maybe you can reconfigure this, or perhaps it is easier to reinstall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently using `rvmsudo` works. Thanks for your help guys!