# Phusion Passenger error -bash: passenger-memory-stats: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

After successfully installing Passenger using gem, I am getting the following errors as indicated in the image below
[image]

I came across the followiing [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051743/phusion-passenger-not-starting-sudo-passenger-command-not-found) but that did not help much.
Any pointers in the right direction will be very much appreciated